# What is the standard directory for javadocs and other documents in a gradle project for a java library?

Tags: java, gradle, javadoc, lib

I have started to develop a java (11) library. I am using Gradle (7.0) for the build and git/GitHub for the source repository.

Currently my project directory has the following structure

```
    myproject
       gradle
       gradlew
       settings.gradle
       docs
       myproject-lib
          src
          build
             ...
            docs
               javadoc
       README.MD
       build.gradle
       ...
```

This is (almost) the layout generated with `gradle init`, but with the addition of a docs directory at the top level (I have omited some directories, files etc.).

When I run `gradlew javadoc` the javadoc files are generated in `$projectDir/build/docs/javadoc`

I would prefer them in the top level docs directory under a sub-directory `javadocs` - my rational is that all documentation is in the same, easy to find, place. This is easy enough to do in gradle, but is this a standard practice or will this cause problems later?

Comment: I believe they shouldn't be commited in the repository but generated from java sources on build and that's why they are in the build directory which is usually not commited in cvs. That way they are always up to date. If you wish to publish them for a released version for example you could do it when building/publishing that release - the javadoc jar could be deployed to a maven repo or a website could be build from them etc

Comment: Thanks. This is starting to clear things up for me. I guess I should be looking at triggering
a CI build task (currently using GitHub actions) on release to publish them.